# How to print the primary key identifier instead of Object using lombok

Tags: java, lombok

How to print `UserRel (from.getId(), rt.toString(), to.getId())` using Lombok.`toString`, I don't want to print the entire object in `log.trace` method but print the primary key identifiers, is there a way to override and achieve what I am looking for

```java
    @Slf4j
    public class UserRel {
    
        @JsonProperty("from")
        @ToString.Exclude
        private User from;
    
        @JsonProperty("rt")
        private Rtype rtype;
    
        @JsonProperty("to")
        @ToString.Exclude
        private User to;
    }
```

Comment: You can override the toString() method

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

**Option 1:** Put `@ToString.Exclude` on every field except for the id of your `User` class. For example:

```
@Data
public class User {
    private Long id;
    @ToString.Exclude
    private String name;
    @ToString.Exclude
    private String email;
}
```

**Option 2:** Use the `onlyExplicitlyIncluded` modifier for `@ToString` and include only the id.

```
@Data
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class User {
    @ToString.Include
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

**Option 3:** Override `toString()` as you want without Lombok.

```
@Data
public class UserRel {
    private User from;
    private User to;
    private String type;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserRel{from=%d, to=%d, type='%s'}".formatted(from.getId(), to.getId(), type);
    }
}
```